# Eye of Cthulhu in Terraria Xbox 360 edition

Tags: terraria-console

I was playing Terraria and I summoned the Eye of Cthulhu and got killed. I was wondering, can I manually respawn it again and/or will it respawn again by its self?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. Well, both. If you don't defeat the eye, it'll just respawn eventually.  You can always spawn him manually whether or not you have beaten him.